# Questions about moduls and return statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return, modulus

I have two questions about this of code.
Can someone explain me, what the if statement is doing exactly. I know that `count` has to increment every time the test is true, but I'm not sure what the this `n % i == 0` is doing.

My second question is, how can I print the return statement's answer on the console?

```
int n = 10;
countFactors(n);
   }
   public static int countFactors(int n){
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
         if (n % i == 0) //this line
         count++;
      }
      return count;
   }
}
```

Comment: `n % i == 0` means `n` divides evenly by `i` (the remainder of `n/i` is 0)

Comment: that if statement is not created properly and will not compile. The boolean statement in the parens is testing whether n is divisible by i

Comment: Your code is somehow , some way incomplete and not verifiable.

Comment: System.out.println?

Comment: did you understand what the line means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It count the number of divisor in your range `1-n` so for example :

if `n = 10` the result will be `4` because there are 4 divisor:

```
1
2
5
10
```

and about how you print in console :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
System.out.println("Number or disivor = " + count);
```

You can learn here : [Table of divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_divisors)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't print the result, only the divisors.

Comment: yes @ItamarGreen  i know that, i think he mean to print the divisors not the result, ok i will edit my answer for you :)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's much better

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the name of the method suggests, the count represents the number of divisors that `n` has.

The if statement tests the following: *Is `n` divisible by `i`?*. in other words: Is `n/i` a whole number?

if you were to use:

```
if(n%i == 1)
```

instead, then it would count the numbers for which: `n/i has a remainder of 1`.

in order to print the return statement, you can add this line just before the `return`:

```
public static int countFactors(int n){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0) 
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);//adding this
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: @EJP better now? XD

Answer (score 0):

The % operator (known as the remainder or Modulus operator) basically divides a number by another and gives you the remainder and nothing else. For instance, if you do 4 % 2, it would give you 0 because 2 goes into 4 evenly. If you would do 4 % 3 it would give you 1 because that's the remainder of 4 / 3. Also look at this website: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html

The `countFactors` method loops 1 to n and includes n. If you do 10 % 1, you would get 0 because one goes into 10 evenly so the count would be incremented.